# when do you use Input shape vs batch_shape in keras?

Tags: keras, shapes

I don't find API that explains keras Input.

When should you use shape attribute vs batch_shape attribute?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Keras source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py):

> ## Arguments
>
> ```
>     shape: A shape tuple (integer), not including the batch size.
>         For instance, `shape=(32,)` indicates that the expected input
>         will be batches of 32-dimensional vectors.
>     batch_shape: A shape tuple (integer), including the batch size.
>         For instance, `batch_shape=(10, 32)` indicates that
>         the expected input will be batches of 10 32-dimensional vectors.
>         `batch_shape=(None, 32)` indicates batches of an arbitrary number
>         of 32-dimensional vectors.
> ```

The batch size is how many examples you have in your training data.

You can use any. Personally I never used "batch_shape". When you use "shape", your batch can be any size, you don't have to care about it.

`shape=(32,)` means exactly the same as `batch_shape=(None,32)`

Comment: how about `shape=(2, 32)` where I want to pass arbitrary batches of matrices of size `2*32`.  will it work or should I use `batch_shape=(None,2, 32)`?

Comment: Both things are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Daniel's answer, one case I've found where it's necessary to specify `batch_shape` instead of `shape` to an `Input` layer is when you are using stateful LSTMs in the functional API. It's described well in [Phillipe Remy's blog](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/). In short, the stateful mode allows you to keep the hidden state values in an LSTM across batches (they usually get reset every batch if the default `stateful=False` is set). That means it needs knowledge about the batch size in order to shape everything properly. If you don't do this, it yells at you:

```
ValueError: If a RNN is stateful, it needs to know its batch size. Specify the batch size of your input tensors: 
    - If using a Sequential model, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_input_shape` argument to your first layer.
    - If using the functional API, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_shape` argument to your Input layer.
```

The second point is the relevant one here. If using LSTM with `stateful=True` in the functional API, you need to set `batch_shape` for your `Input` layers.