# Keras concatenate with shapes [(1, 8), (None, 32)]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My network consists of **LSTM and Dense parts connected together** by the other Dense part and I **cannot concatenate inputs of size [(1, 8), (None, 32)]**. `Reshape` and `Flatten` do not work.

Here's the architecture:

```py
def build_model_equal(dropout_rate=0.25):

    curve_input_1 = Input(batch_shape=(1, None, 1), name='curve_input_1')
    lstm_1 = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1)(curve_input_1)
    lstm_1 = LSTM(64, dropout=0.1)(lstm_1)
    lstm_out = Dense(8)(lstm_1)

    metadata_input = Input(shape=(31,), name='metadata_input')

    dense_1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(metadata_input)
    dense_1 = BatchNormalization()(dense_1)
    dense_1 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(dense_1)

    dense_out = Dense(32)(dense_1)

    x = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm_out, dense_out], axis=1)

    output_hidden = Dense(64)(x)
    output_hidden = BatchNormalization()(output_hidden)
    output_hidden = Dropout(dropout_rate)(output_hidden)

    output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(output_hidden)

    model = Model(inputs=[curve_input_1, metadata_input], outputs=output)
    return model
```

When I train this model via

```py
model.fit([x_train, x_metadata], y_train,
    validation_data=[[x_valid, x_metadata_val], y_valid], 
    epochs=n_epoch,
    batch_size=n_batch, shuffle=True, 
    verbose=2, callbacks=[checkPoint]
)
```

I get an error

> ValueError: A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. **Got inputs shapes: [(1, 8), (None, 32)]**

When I add `Reshape` layer like

```py
dense_out = Dense(32)(dense_4)
dense_out = Reshape((1, 32))(dense_out)

x = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm_out, dense_out], axis=1)
```

I get

> ValueError: A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. **Got inputs shapes: [(1, 8), (None, 1, 32)]**

`Reshape` layer `input_shape=(32,)` or `input_shape=(None, 32)` parameters do not change the situation, error and shapes are the same.

Adding `Reshape` to LSTM like

```py
curve_input_1 = Input(batch_shape=(1, None, 1), name='curve_input_1')
lstm_first_1 = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, name='lstm_first_1')(curve_input_1)
lstm_second_1 = LSTM(64, dropout=0.1, name='lstm_second_1')(lstm_first_1)
lstm_out = Dense(8)(lstm_second_1)
lstm_out = Reshape((None, 8))(lstm_out)
```

Produces an error

> ValueError: Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.

Changing `concatenate` `axis` parameter to `0`, `1` and `-1` doesn't help.

Changing `Dense` part input shape doesn't help. When I do `metadata_input = Input(shape=(1, 31), name='metadata_input')` instead of metadata_input = Input(shape=(31,), name='metadata_input') it produces an error with `[(1, 8), (None, 1, 32)]` dimensions.

My guess is that I need to transform data either to `[(1, 8), (1, 32)]` or to `[(None, 8), (None, 32)]` shape, but `Reshape` and `Flatten` layers didn't help.

There should be an easy way to do that that I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem could be the use `batch_shape` for the first `Input` and `shape` for the second one.

With the first input, your batch size is hardcoded as `1` and your input data has 2 extra dimensions, `None` (unspecified) and `1`.

For the second input, since you are using `shape`, you are declaring that your input has batch size unespecified and data has one dimension of `31` values.

Note that using `shape=(31,)` is the same as using `batch_shape=(None, 31)` (from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792106/when-do-you-use-input-shape-vs-batch-shape-in-keras)).

Aligning both is working for me, at least at model declaration time (I was unable to run the fit though, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something and this solution doesn't fit your use case.

So, to summarize, you can try:

```
curve_input_1 = Input(batch_shape=(1, None, 1), name='curve_input_1')
metadata_input = Input(batch_shape=(1, 31), name='metadata_input')
```

Or:

```
curve_input_1 = Input(batch_shape=(1, None, 1), name='curve_input_1')
metadata_input = Input(batch_shape=(1, 31), name='metadata_input')
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
curve_input_1 = Input(shape=(None, 1, ), name='curve_input_1')
metadata_input = Input(shape=(31, ), name='metadata_input')
```

Please, let me know it this worked or lead you in a good direction!